# How do I extract VBA variables and arrays using Java?

Tags: java, vba, excel

Just starting out using Java, but I have a lot of code in VBA. I'm trying to extract some of the variables and arrays created in VBA so I can use them in Java.

I'm using Apache POI, so I can create a new variable or array by drawing it directly from cells in excel. But is there a way directly extract a variable/value set in VBA?

For example in VBA:

```
DIM variable1 AS LONG
variable1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Is there a way of extracting variable1 into Java or will VBA/excel 'forget' what variable1 was too quickly to be useful if it's not put in a cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use POI to something like

```
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues ();

    CellReference cr = new CellReference("B5"); 
    Cell cell = sh.getRow(cr.getRow()).getCell(cr.getCol());

    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```